# I am stuck at a question (about bias current and offset voltage)

Tags: amplifier, bias, dc-offset, non-inverting

So I was doing the following question from sedra smith microelectronics:
[image]

I have managed to do all parts in the question except part d. I am stuck at part d.

The way I have tried is the following: On the non-inverting lead of the op amp, there is a Voltage offset sources attached along with a resister to compensate for the bias current. I used superposition. First I replace the bias current source inside the op amp with an open circuit and so the voltage seen by positive terminal of the op amp is Vos. And then I replace the Vos with a short circuit and also find output voltage. But my answer is not correct. The correct answer for part d is 22mV. Can someone tell me how to solve for part d?

Answer (score 1):

You have this circuit, with total error input of 2.2 milliVolts; Vout is 100X larger.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXb8YJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>